# RavenDb get raw JSON without deserialization

Tags: c#, ravendb

I need to recover JSON stored in RavenDb database knowing its `Id`. What's tricky here, I need to get it before it is deserialized into an actual object. Reason for that is, I need it in exact same form it was first stored in, regardless what happens to the CLR class (it can drastically change or even be removed), because it is an audit of previous state (it's only going to be displayed at this point, I won't use it for anything else).

If I go with

```
using (var session = Store.OpenSession())
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(session.Load<object>(id));
}
```

I get JSON reflecting current state of underlying type, probably because it's stored in `@metadata.Raven-Clr-Type`. So I don't see removed properties, and I do see empty properties that didn't exist when it was first stored.

I wanted to use `DocumentStore.DatabaseCommands.Get()` to get `RavenJObject`, but it is already removed in 4.1 in favor of `Advanced.DocumentQuery` and I couldn't find a way to do what I want using it.

I've also tried using own `AbstractIndexCreationTask` like this:

```
class Object_AsJson : AbstractIndexCreationTask<JsonObject>
{
    public Configuration_AsJson()
    {
        Map = configuration => configuration.Select(x => AsJson(x).Select(y => y.Value));
    }
}
```

But `session.Load` doesn't accept `TIndexCreator`, and in `session.Query` I can't get `Id` because I don't have any properties of an object to make query from.

---

**Example:**

If I have this class:

```
public class Person
{
    string FullName { get; set; }
    int Age { get; set; }
}
```

And I store a new document `new Person { FullName = "John Samson", Age = 42 }`, under `Id` `person/A-1`, yet half year later I decide to modify this class to:

```
public class Person
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
    int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to see how JSON of `person/A-1` looks like, but an attempt to load it maps it to current state of `Person`, so I will get:

```
{
  "FirstName": null,
  "LastName": null,
  "Age": 42
}
```

And I want to get

```
{
  "FullName": "John Samson",
  "Age": 42
}
```

I can see my desired result in RavenDb Studio GUI, but I need to get it in my code to display it in my application.

Does anyone have any idea how to handle that? Just a hint in right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: What is it that you actually need ? If you need a Previous State of the document then use the Revisions Feature to get its previous state.
See: https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.1/csharp/server/extensions/revisions

Comment: @Danielle sadly, it doesn't meet my needs. I need full audit, which means I need to know why was it changed, by whom and when. Revisions can't cover first two. It also doesn't solve main issue, that it will be mapped to current class, and I need to see how it looked like at the moment it was saved, which currently I can only do from RavenDb Studio (which makes me believe it's possible to retrieve this JSON)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, so I've finally found out how to do it, so I'll leave it here for anyone who, for some reason, wants to do the same.

Basically you just have to make an instance of `GetDocumentsCommand` and execute it. In my case it looks like this:

```
using (var session = Store.OpenSession(database))
{
    var command = new GetDocumentsCommand(id, null, false);
    session.Advanced.RequestExecutor.Execute(command, session.Advanced.Context);
    var result = command.Result.Results.FirstOrDefault();
    var json = result?.ToString(); // At this point you already have your JSON
    var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
    jObject.Remove("@metadata"); // If you don't want metadata in your JSON
    jObject.Add("Id", id); // Because Id does not appear to be part of JSON
    return jObject;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/ravendb/book/blob/v4.0/Ch03/Ch03.md#revisions-and-auditing

"....
**Auditing** is a bit different. While revisions tell you what changed, auditing tells you by
whom and typically what for. RavenDB supports this kind of auditing using client-side **listeners**,
which can provide additional context for the document whenever it’s changed.
...."

See how to **implement auditing mechanism with Event Handlers**: https://github.com/ravendb/book/blob/v4.0/Ch04/Ch04.md#event-handlers

https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.1/Csharp/migration/client-api/document-store#listeners

use something similar to:

```
store.OnBeforeStore += (sender, args) =>
{
args.DocumentMetadata["Modified-By"] =
RequestContext.Principal.Identity.GetUserId();
};
```

Comment: The point is.... I already have auditing implemented, and it works fine. I don't need help in relation to **storing** my documents, this suggested way has exact same problem as I have right now. My question is only about **loading** them, so I get stored JSON, not an object that will be different depending how the class changed over time. I'll just add an example to my question to make it clear what I need to achieve.

Comment: I've added an example to visualize what my actual problem is.